# Refusing service to an IPv4 address with SetEnv

Tags: apache-2.2

I have two servers running load balancing for a website, they have the same configuration.

I want to block access to my site from a certain IP (let's pretend it's 127.1.2.3).

```
  <Directory "/var/www/html/example.com">
        AllowOverride all      
        SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For ^127\.1\.2\.3 attacker
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from env=!attacker
        # ErrorDocument 403 http://google.com
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-eruby
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    </Directory>
```

Here is Apache version in two server:

- Apache/2.2.3
- Apache/2.2.18

The problems occurs with server which run Apache 2.2.3. It not only blocks attacker's IP, but also blocks all others. While with the same configuration, the second server runs normally.

I went through Apache documentation to ensure my configuration syntax isn't wrong. I also run `httpd -t` and the ouput show that my `Syntax OK`.

What can be problem with my `env` configuration?

Comment: This isn't a great way to stop a DDoS attack.

Comment: Yes, of course. But I want to know why `set env` in Apache doesn't work? I don't ask how to anti DDOS.

Comment: Yes, but why are you doing it this way?

Comment: Because It's the first thing to do, to make my website online. If I don't ban attacker's IP, my website will went down until the other frontend admin (HAPROXY) solved this problem. Time is money.

Comment: Why not do it in IPtables, and get it lower down the stack?

Comment: I have my own reason. And again, Ban IP in Apache configuration is only the temp solution. Please focus on my question, what happen with Apache `set env`.

Comment: No. I won't and  you can't make me.

Comment: A few notes: First, if it was a single IP address, it isn't a DDoS attack. Second, [sf] has a very strong culture of "doing it right". If you're _not_ doing it right, you're going to be called out and you should expect that. You may have good reasons for using a less-than-ideal approach, but they should be discussed.

Answer (score 3):

So you have two versions of Apache and you've found that it doesn't work on 2.2.3 but works on 2.2.18?

Upgrade the 2.2.3 server to 2.2.18.

Answer (score 3):

Use this configuration instead:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "(,| |^)192\.168\.1\.1(,| |$)" attacker
Order Allow,deny
Deny from env=attacker
Allow From all

....
```

If this doesn't work, then 2.2.3 of Apache is too old for this module to function properly.